# Incorrect data being pulled from a SharePoint list to Power BI

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

When I pull data from a SharePoint list into Power BI, the values are pulled incorrectly for columns having the data type -

1. *Person or Group* - instead of names, numerical values are pulled. I guess these are the IDs of the values
2. *Lookup* - instead of the actual values, '[list]' is pulled in a nested column. When I expand, numerical values are shown. Again, seems like IDs

All other data types are pulled properly.

To work around this problem, I first pull the data from the list to Excel and then to PBI. However, I want to eliminate this manual step as the list will have frequent updates and I will need to pull the list data into Power BI regularly.

What should be done to pull the actual values as they appear in the list?

Answer (score 0):

For the lookup columns: You need to pull in the lists where the lookup values are being looked up from and then create a relationship based on ID.

For the People: Look here:[fully explained how to deal with Person object](https://www.sharepointeurope.com/using-power-bi-to-report-on-person-fields-in-sharepoint-part-two/)

Comment: Thanks @Djerro-Neth,

I used the _FieldValuesAsText_ column in the Query Editor. But I also like your suggestion of pulling all tables and creating a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I did some looking around and was able to find a solution.

Using the *FieldValuesAsText* column in the Query Editor, I got the values in the table. values for both column types were available. Since, I only needed the text values it solved the purpose.